# Javascript PHP chunk video and save into Database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
    window.addEventListener("load", () => {    
    var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes: "html5",
        browse_button: "upload",
        url: "../upload.php",
        chunk_size: "10mb", // <<<<<<< Here is my problem
        filters: {
        max_file_size: "100gb",

        .... THIS CODE HERE DOESN'T MATTER .....
    });
```

This is my upload.php

```php
    function verbose ($ok=1, $info="") {
      if ($ok==0) { http_response_code(400); }
      exit(json_encode(["ok"=>$ok, "info"=>$info]));
    }

    if (empty($_FILES) || $_FILES["file"]["error"]) {
      verbose(0, "Failed to move uploaded file.");
    }
    
    $filePath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "videos";
    if (!file_exists($filePath)) { if (!mkdir($filePath, 0777, true)) {
      verbose(0, "Failed to create $filePath");
    }}

    $fileName       = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $filePath       = $filePath . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileName;
    $dateformat     = date("Y-m-d-H:i:s");
    $fileSize       = $_FILES["file"]["size"]; // <<<<< HERE IS MY PROBLEM
    $title          = pathinfo($fileName,PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    
    $chunk = isset($_REQUEST["chunk"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunk"]) : 0;
    $chunks = isset($_REQUEST["chunks"]) ? intval($_REQUEST["chunks"]) : 0;
    $out = @fopen("{$filePath}.part", $chunk == 0 ? "wb" : "ab");
    if ($out) {
        $in = @fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "rb");
            if ($in) {
                while ($buff = fread($in, 4096)) { 
                    fwrite($out, $buff); 
                }
            }else{
                echo "err";
            }
            @fclose($in);
            @fclose($out);
            @unlink($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
    }else{
        verbose(0, "Failed to open output stream"); 
    }
    
    if (!$chunks || $chunk == $chunks - 1) { 
        $rename = 'videos/'.generateKey($pdo); // simple function to generate random string ( 123asdjjn124 and so on)
        $databaseName = str_replace('videos/','', $rename); // remove videos/ from the string
        rename("{$filePath}.part", $rename);
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO videos(title,size,date,link) VALUES(:title,:size,:date,:link)");
        $stmt->bindParam(':title',$title,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':size',$fileSize,PDO::PARAM_STR); // <<<<< HERE IS MY PROBLEM
        $stmt->bindParam(':date',$dateformat,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':link',$databaseName,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
    }

    verbose(1, "Upload OK");
```

Now when I upload a file, everything is entered beautifully but the size of the "chunk_size" is always entered instead of the correct size of the file. Does anyone have an idea why this is so? It also makes no difference if I change the file size, it always takes the "chunk_size".

Any advice is helpful
Here I have another screenshot to illustrate how I mean it. https://prnt.sc/QW-zXtrb6RuY

Comment: And why are you storing videos to a DB? This makes no sense. Instead upload the video files to a "repository" and reference them via your db.

Comment: Can you just call `filesize` on `$rename` or similar?

Comment: @Chris Haas I didn't think of it, but your thought process made it work. Thanks for your helpful comment.

`$fileSize = filesize($rename);` fixed the problem